# JavaScript Hex Escape Character decoding

Tags: javascript

Is there any JavaScript function which does the same thing with JavaScript hex escaped string what below mentioned python code does??

```
>>> a = "\x41\x42\x43\x44"
>>> a.encode('string-escape')
'ABCD'
```

Since, I'm getting the value from a text field using getElementById.value , i think the string is similar to `\\x41\\x42\\x43\\x44`

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

`unescape` can help you

```
unescape("\x41\x42\x43\x44") //ABCD
```

Comment: Thanks for your response can you please see my edits in question.

Answer (score 0):

See comment about this being a duplicate question. Essentially there is no need to do anything in JavaScript.

```
var a = "\x41\x42\x43\x44";
a // "ABCD"
a.charAt(0); // "A"
a === "ABCD" // true
```

UPDATE: A quick dirty hack is to use something like the following. It's a bit late for me but I am sure there is a cleaner method for this.

This takes each hex chunk, converts it to a decimal value and finally uses that value as a character code to replace the original hex chunk.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('my-el');

el.onblur = function () {
  var val = this.value;
  
  var newVal = val.replace(/\\x([0-9A-F]{2})/ig, function() {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(arguments[1], 16));
  });
  alert(newVal);
};
```

```html
<p>Enter \x41\x42\x43\x44</p>
<input type="text" id="my-el">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated the question.Can you please take a look now.

Comment: @Dev.K. Updated the answer, but again this information was basically in the referenced duplicate answer.